# Python program to verify telephone number entered correctly

Tags: python

Here's what I have so far although it isn't properly working. Any suggestions for changes appreciated.

```
def get_telephone_number(areacode, prefix, number):
    set1 = areacode[0:3]
    set2 = prefix[0:3]
    set3 = number[-3:]

    telephone_number=set1 + '-' + set2 + '-' + set3

    return get_telephone_number


def valid_telephone_number(telephone_number):
    correct_length = False
    proper_hyphens = False
    has_digits = False

    if len(telephone_number) == 12:
        correct_length = True

    for ch in telephone_number:
        if ch [3, 7] == '-':
            proper_hypens = True
        if ch.isdigit():
            has_digits = True

    if correct_length and proper_hypens and has_digits:
        is_valid = True
    else:
        is_valid = False

    return is_valid
###########

import telephone_number

def main():
    phone_number = input('Enter your telephone number: ')

    while not phone_number.valid_telephone_number(telephone_number):  
        print('That number is invalid.')
        phone_number = input('Enter your telephone number: ')

    print('That is a valid entry.')

main()
```

Comment: You're probably better off using Google's [`libphonenumber`](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) than trying to do this yourself. There's a Python port as well: [`python-phonenumbers`](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers)

Comment: It's part of a Python assignment on manipulating strings, so I'm limited to that now.  Thank you for your input and taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the exact format you want but using a regex would probably be easier:

```
import  re
s ="043-4443-344"
n = re.match("^\d+-\d+-\d+$",s)
if n:
    print(n.group())
```

`"^\d+-\d+-\d+$"` will match a string starting with one or more digits followed by a hyphen, one or more digits  followed by a hyphen and ending with one or more digits. If you want to allow a specific amount of digits you can use, for example `^\d{3,5}` to make the area code be between 3-5 digits long.

Your first check should probably be `if len(phone_number) != 12` as there is no point going any further if it is not.

If you want to do it  without a regex then you can do something like the following:

```
def valid_telephone_number(inp):
    # make sure len is 12 and all char at index 3 and 7  are -
    if not all(inp[x] == "-" for x in [3,7])and len(inp) == 12:
        return False
    # will be True if all that is left are digits after removing the - else False
    return inp.replace("-", "", 3).isdigit()



def main():
    while True:
        phone_number = input('Enter your telephone number: ')
        check = valid_telephone_number(phone_number)
        # will be True for a valid num so return the formatted input
        if check:
            return check
        # or else print message telling use the input was invalid and ask again
        print('{} is a not valid entry, please try again.'.format(phone_number))
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is a Python assignment on manipulating string, so I'm kind of limited with the instructor's preferences.  I appreciate your taking the time to respond with helpful suggestions!

Comment: @Treece, what are the specifications?

Comment: Here;s the instructor's directions:  write a program that will verify a phone number has been properly entered.  User will enter phone number and the program will check that it meets the requirements by passing 3 test in order (1) does it contain 12 characters (2) does it have hypens at the proper places and (3) if you remove the hypens are all the remaining characters digits.  If a phone number fails any of the tests it is invalid.  Program should verify input phone number is valid and report it as either valid or invalid.

Comment: @Treece, the edit should be close to what you need, you might need to change the indexes based on where the hypens should be

Comment: Another question:  Wouldn't the index of the hypens in a telephone number formatted 123-456-7899 be [3] and [7]?  I'm getting invalid when it should be valid.